# Can you make a field unique in a content type in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have an `employee` content type and it have an `id` field.

Can I make the `id` field unique (so that Drupal would prevent me from inputting the same `id` more than once by mistake)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [field validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) module. It allows you to set a field as unique on per content type basis.

Alternatively, if you have access to/are a developer, then it's quite simple to alter the form and include your own validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contrib module [unique_content_field_validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_content_field_validation)